# Cannot cast object 'class centaur.demo.Profile' with class 'java.lang.Class' to class 'centaur.demo.Profile'

Tags: java, exception, grails, groovy, classcastexception

Please help me to fix this issue. Thank you!

I am working on a **Grails-5.2.4** project with **Java 1.8**. Class Loader is not working as expected.

**I am getting class cast exception for the following piece of code.**

```
def index() {
    Profile profile = getClass().classLoader.loadClass("centaur.demo.Profile") as Profile
}
```

**Below is the exception details:**

```
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'class centaur.demo.Profile' with class 'java.lang.Class' to class 'centaur.demo.Profile'
    at org.grails.web.converters.ConverterUtil.invokeOriginalAsTypeMethod(ConverterUtil.java:147)
    at org.grails.web.converters.ConvertersExtension.asType(ConvertersExtension.groovy:56)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at centaur.demo.IndexController.index(IndexController.groovy:10)
    ... 13 common frames omitted
```

[image]

Expected behavior:

The line below should return an object of class Profile.

```
getClass().classLoader.loadClass("centaur.demo.Profile")
```

This is working fine with Grails 3.3.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line:

```
getClass().classLoader.loadClass("centaur.demo.Profile")
```

should return you a `Class` object.

check out the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#loadClass-java.lang.String-

so, you could assign result to Class:

```
Class c = getClass().classLoader.loadClass("centaur.demo.Profile")
```

you could instantiate class:

```
def profile = getClass().classLoader.loadClass("centaur.demo.Profile").newInstance()
```

but the following code could fail:

```
centaur.demo.Profile profile = getClass().classLoader.loadClass("centaur.demo.Profile").newInstance()
```

when class loader used for declaration is different from the one returned by `getClass().classLoader`

Comment: Hi @daggett, what if I don't want to create new instance but load existing record from DB?

Comment: Can't understand how the question related to loading record from DB ..

Comment: Actually, I am facing an issue similar to this where data is being fetched from the database. Can you please give me your email/skype etc to share the details? If you can fix that I'll pay you for that. Paid task. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As the name suggests [`ClassLoader#loadClass`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#loadClass-java.lang.String-) returns an instance of `java.lang.Class`. You have to instantiate the class to get an object of its referenced type using `new Profile(...)` or by calling [`Class#newInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance--) on the result of `loadClass` (provided your Profile class has an accessible default constructor)

Comment: Thank you Florian, you explained it very well.